# Set left position of div and each div there after is doubled

Tags: jquery, css, position

I have a set of divs all in widths of 960px. I need to position these absolutely but set them apart 960px apart.

So, for example. the first div would have a left position of 0, then the second div 960px, then the third div 1920px, and then the third 2880px etc.

Is this possible? I'm thinking using jQuery and the each(); function but can't work it out.

Many thanks,
R

Comment: What CSS is in place for these divs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/irejoh/1/edit)**

```
$('.div').each(function( i ){
  $(this).css({ left: 960 * i });
});
```

Simple using the `.each()` callback (indexInArray)
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/